# could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (2)

Tags: python, numpy

I want to simply assign 1 into all list of a ndarray.

before,

```
[5.2 4.1]
[6.9 3.1]
[5.9 3.2]
[5.6 2.8]
[6.7 3.3]......................
```

what i need,

```
[1 5.2 4.1]
[1 6.9 3.1]
[1 5.9 3.2]
[1 5.6 2.8]
[1 6.7 3.3]
```

i am trying to iterate and insert, then try to assign the returned value. but i have a problem with the shape. found the above error.

```
for i in range(len(X_train)):
  X_train[i] = np.insert(X_train[i], 0,1)
```

then i tried to reshape before loop:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(len(X_train), 3)
```

i found this error:
***cannot reshape array of size 210 into shape (105,3)***

but the actual shape:

```
>>X_train.shape
```

output: ***(105, 2)***

I am looking for any solution and also the reason.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `insert` docs:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])
>>> a
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
>>> np.insert(a, 1, 5, axis=1)
array([[1, 5, 1],
       [2, 5, 2],
       [3, 5, 3]])
```

So taking your case - act on the whole array, and specify the axis:

```
In [184]: arr = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,2))
In [185]: arr
Out[185]: 
array([[7, 5],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 4]])
In [186]: arr1 = np.insert(arr,0,1,axis=1)   
In [187]: arr1
Out[187]: 
array([[1, 7, 5],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 4]])
```

Many of the numpy functions take an `axis` (or `axes`) parameter.  Use it.

Answer (score 1):

One Liner:

```
import numpy as np
X_train = np.hstack((X_train, np.ones((X_train.shape[0], 1), dtype=X_train.dtype)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array of ones and fill all but the first column with your starting array.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(
[[5.2, 4.1],
[6.9, 3.1],
[5.9, 3.2],
[5.6, 2.8],
[6.7, 3.3]])
sh =arr.shape

new_arr = np.ones((sh[0],sh[1]+1))
new_arr[:,1:] = arr

print(new_arr)
```

Output :

```
[[1.  5.2 4.1]
 [1.  6.9 3.1]
 [1.  5.9 3.2]
 [1.  5.6 2.8]
 [1.  6.7 3.3]]
```

Comment: its a dataset actually, so i have to iterate